# Permission denied for sickrage and transmission

Tags: 16.04, server, mount, fstab, transmission

So I set up a mounted shared folder in fstab doing the following:

```
//ALEX-PC/kodi   /mnt/kodi   auto    user,pass=***,rw, async    0 0
```

The folder successfully mounts and as a user in ssh I can delete and add folders to this mapped drive. However whenever I add a show to sickrage or add a torrent on transmission it fails with permission denied.

I have the permission on my windows PC(the PC that contains the mapped drive) to have read/write enabled for everyone.

Any ideas?

*Edit
Using `ls -l /mnt` causes nothing to return and it just freezes

Comment: What are the permissions for `/mnt/kodi`?

Comment: I believe 700, I'm not highly acquainted with permissions

Comment: Just do a `ls -l /mnt` and tell us what it says on the `kodi` line.

Comment: It just freezes with no output, even with sudo. I have to close the SSH session to gain back control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the line to the options
`file_mode=0777, dir_mode=0777` and removing `rw`
and changing `auto` to `cifs`

SickRage & Transmissions was able to write to the mapped drive.